# Is there any function in Java(swing) through which one cannot switch or minimize that particular frame or window?

Tags: java, swing, awt, desktop-application

Like we all know, due to pandemic students are giving their tests from home through their PCs.
So, I'm creating a MCQ based Desktop Application in java using awt and swing,
where students cannot switch their window or minimize it to search for their answers on Google.
So, is it possible that one cannot switch their window or minimize it during their test?

Comment: You're describing a kiosk application, and no, pure Java doesn't delve into the bowels of the OS and thereby cannot make some aspects of that happen. Java apps. aim to be guests on the user's machine, not cops. Besides - tests should be open book / open internet these days - just tell students who are constantly saying "OK Google!" to please be quiet so as not to activate all the other Android devices in the room.

Comment: @Lakshan *"Does this answer your question?"* No. No it doesn't. All that does is bring the window to the top under usual conditions. If another app. is trying to be 'always on top' the other app. is likely to win, and it is not immune to intervention by the user themselves.

Comment: *"through their PCs"* BTW - did you already get the parents to remove the student's phone & table devices from the room where they're doing this PC based test? *"OK Google!"* .. *"Hey Siri!"*